# neo4j unwind param passing issue

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to pass a graph ql arguments array in cypher query. I am having difficulty making query work. I can see the parameter passed correctly while doing console log. However, when I try to utilize with node js. Neo4j driver is not doing anything. I think I am doing something wrong. Could anyone please guide me.

using neo4j 3.5.12

```
const query = `UNWIND $list as batch
match ((u:user { ohrid: ${ctx.ohrid}})-[:FILE_SHARED_WITH| FILE_SHARED_WITH_GROUP| MEMBER_OF_GROUP*..2]-(f:file)) where f.uuid = batch.uuid
SET f.documentStatus = batch.documentStatus
return f as files`;

const queryParams = { list: args.documents }; // args.document is arguments from gql mutation

const result = await session.run(query, queryParams);
```

if I use the same query in neo4j browser it works fine

```
UNWIND [{id: 2, documentStatus: "unpublished"}, { id: 32, documentStatus: "unpublished"}] as batch
match ((u:user { ohrid: 850046714})-[:FILE_SHARED_WITH| FILE_SHARED_WITH_GROUP| MEMBER_OF_GROUP*..2]-(f:file)) where ID(f) = batch.id and any(x in batch.documentStatus where x in ['published', 'unpublished'])
SET f.documentStatus = batch.documentStatus
return f
```

Cheers
~ Meet

Comment: What is the error returned by the driver ? Can you also share the content of a `JSON.stringify(args.documents)` to see if there something wrong with it.

Comment: The query you used in the browser has a *very* different `WHERE` clause. Also, are you sure that the `${ctx.ohrid}` value is `850046714`, or that the `$list` parameter has the same list as used in the browser query?

Comment: As others said, we don't really know what values you pass for those params. In particular, I guess `ctx.ohrid` may not be properly set/used. If you couldn't figure it out, enable query log in neo4j server and see what query you get there.

Comment: its fixed now thanks